# Issue in mylisting theme at result page

Tags: html, list, web-scraping, actionresult, directory-listing

In mylisting theme when i search for listing category and region in search form then in result page only category tittle is show on page region functionality  works but regions tittle is not show on page

i add search & filter plugin for result page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.